# How do I turn off text overwriting when using gnatmake/GPS for ada?

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

Okay so I somehow changed the settings in GPS where it is overwriting my text when I type. I've tried so much stuff to try to fix it and I'm tired. Googling doesn't seem to help. Do any of yall know how to fix it? I can't stand coding when the text goes over the other text.

ive tried all the F commands and ctrl I and stuff that it might be.

Comment: Insert button on keyboard?

Comment: dang @TimurSamkharadze you right. I'm just dumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the insert key on the keyboard. dang im dumb.